# Isomorphism between finite direct sums of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I consider only commutative rings with unit. Given two finite collections of rings $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{B_j\}_{j=1}^m$ s.t. $$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i \cong \bigoplus_{j=1}^m B_j$$
Does it necessarily hold that:

1. $n = m$
2. $\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}\exists j \in \{1,\dots,m\}$ s.t. $A_i \cong B_j$ ?

I think that the second one is false, but I couldn't find a counter example.

Thanks!

Comment: This is trivially false if you take $m=1$ and $B_1=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i$. The question is interesting if you additionally assume that each $A_i,B_j$ is indecomposable, i.e. $A_i\not\simeq X\oplus Y$ for any two nontrivial rings $X,Y$. Or maybe a variant of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A_1=A_2=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B_1=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ which is a counterexample to both claims.